# Is the halting problem decidable for TMs that do not write to the tape?

Tags: undecidability, halting-problem

Is the halting problem decidable for TMs that do not write to the tape?

Once a read only tape TM repeats a configuration, it will loop forever. Therefore, all we have to do to decide the above is construct a different TM(with read and write tape) that’s takes the read only TM as input and checks for a repeat configuration, if one is found, accept, otherwise reject.

Is this correct?

Comment: My question was closed ?

Comment: I didn’t get to finish reading that answer that was posted. I thought it looked helpful. Can you repost as a comment?

Comment: Your question is answered at the link.  Your proof is not complete because of the possibility for the head to wander onto the area of the tape with blank cells, as explained there -- you haven't proven that if the TM doesn't repeat a configuration, it will halt.  Proving that takes some work.  My prior answer had a flaw so I deleted it.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. “ you haven't proven that if the TM doesn't repeat a configuration, it will halt.”  Can’t I just say that if a TM doesn’t repeat a configuration then because there are a finite number of configurations, the TM must finish in finite steps, in other words halt?

Comment: Is this not correct because the situation where it keeps moving to the blanks on the right? And each movement to the right is a new configuration. Does this mean I have to prove that the TM does not move to the right forever? I’m trying to understand the link you gave me but I’m not quite there with it.